# How to store python dict in google spreadsheet and append

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, adsense

The script is generating a dictionary name result

```
 # Display headers.
  for header in result['headers']:
    print('%25s' % header['name'], end=''),
  print()

  # Display results.
  if 'rows' in result:
    for row in result['rows']:
     for cell in row['cells']:
      print('%25s' % cell['value'], end='')
  print()
```

How can I store the header on the top row
and store the results without overwriting & duplicate
in google sheets.
I've already connected CGP and everthing

script: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/blob/9f1b24bbfdecf418ee48ce18bc3422aef835a138/v2/python/generate_report.py

Comment: It appears that repository is private.

Comment: At https://github.com/tonmoyazad?tab=repositories we see you have half a dozen public repos, and `james` isn't one of them.

Comment: Your question asks about modifying a google sheet, yet your posted code makes no mention of that. It is unclear (A.) what you want, and (B.) how we could help you. Show us example data along with the expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/blob/9f1b24bbfdecf418ee48ce18bc3422aef835a138/v2/python/generate_report.py

Comment: I'm going to assume that each of "headers" and "value" is a `str` with no SPACE characters. If so, then the `'%25s'` format string is probably less safe than you would like. Consider rephrasing it as `'%25s '`, or make `end=' '`, or better use `' '.join(...)` so there's no trailing blanks. The concern is that you likely want for code to be able to `.split(...)` such output, yet there is the danger of a value being longer than 24 characters, so no delimiting blank would appear in the output.

Comment: Should I convert the dict to dataframe and store it in google Sheets?